# Apache Solr one to many relationship mapping

Tags: solr, lucene, dataimporthandler

I have the following configured in my db-config.xml

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
            driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://host:port/schema"
            user="username"
            password="password" /> 

   <document name="product">
    <entity name="store" query="select mid,name,display_name,address,email,pincode,b.latitude,b.longitude,city,locality,b.lid,b.locid from business b join locality loc on b.locid = loc.locid join location l on l.lid = loc.lid where b.status='A' and isItemStore ='Y' and mid between  11151 and 11161 ">
        <field column="mid" name="id"/>
        <field column="lid" name="lid"/>
        <field column="locid" name="locid"/>
        <field column="name" name="name"/>
        <field column="display_name" name="display_name"/>
        <field column="address" name="address"/>
        <field column="email" name="email"/>
        <field column="pincode" name="pincode"/>
        <field column="latitude" name="latitude"/>
        <field column="longitude" name="longitude"/>
        <field column="city" name="city"/>
        <field column="locality" name="locality"/>

        <entity name="item" query="select ib.cid,ib.bid,ib.item_id,b.bname,c.cname,ib.description,short_description,
    concat(field_1,' ',field_2,' ',field_3,' ',field_4,' ',field_5,' ',field_6) item_feature,inv.pos_code,sku_count,unit_price,final_price from item_business ib join brand b on ib.bid = b.bid join category c on c.cid=ib.cid join `${store.mid}-inventory-table` inv where ib.status='A'"> 
               <field column="item_id" name="item_id"/>     
               <field column="short_description" name="short_description"/>
               <field column="item_desc" name="item_desc"/>
               <field column="item_feature" name="item_feature"/>
               <field column="bid" name="bid"/>
               <field column="cid" name="cid"/>
               <field column="bname" name="brand_name" />
               <field column="cname" name="category_name" />     
               <field column="pos_code" name="pos_code" />   
               <field column="sku_count" name="sku_count" />     
               <field column="unit_price" name="unit_price" />   
               <field column="final_price" name="final_price" />      
           </entity>
    </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

The below snippet is what I have in schema.xml

```
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>     
     <field name="id" type="tlong" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
     <field name="name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
     <field name="display_name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
     <field name="address" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
     <field name="email" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
     <field name="pincode" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="latitude" type="tdouble" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="longitude" type="tdouble" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="city" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="locality" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="item_id" type="tlong" indexed="true" stored="true"/>       
    <field name="bname" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="cname" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="item_feature" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="item_desc" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="short_description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="pos_code" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>    
    <field name="sku_count" type="tint"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/> 
    <field name="unit_price" type="tdouble"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/> 
    <field name="final_price" type="tdouble"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
```

Solrconfig.xml

```
 <lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-\d.*\.jar" />

   <requestHandler name="/dataimport"  class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="config">db-data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
   </requestHandler
```

I am a beginner in Apache Solr. And I followed Solr wiki to get my server up and running with Jetty server.

Scenario : A store has items and items have attributes.

I get the store information and then with the store I get the items that the store has.

But indexing happens only for one store and one item instead of one store and all the items in one store.

How does the second query in db-config.xml run multiple times to fetch all the items for that store?

And I see there is a multi-value option, but I am not sure how to use it in this context.

Can some one help?

Comment: Let's clarify a few details: What version of solr are you using? I think you are trying to use data import handler (maybe add [dataimporthandler] tag?) Your problem is getting the data into solr not querying it right (at least not yet :) )?

Comment: I am using solr-5.3.1. And I added the dataimport lib to solrconfig.xml .Will update the snippet in the question.

Comment: I've not used data import handler, but reading your description & config again I notice that you might be doing things backwards (vs the normal default strategy in search).  Perhaps you should be making the items the document and denormalizing the store information onto them? For search data is usually denormalized to make the search query fast.